# How to flatten a nested object in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a document of the form:

```json
{
  "employee_addr": {
    "city": "London",
    "street": "Downing Street",
    "apartment": 10
  }

  "age": 58,
  "name": "Boris"
}
```

I want to flatten the document. That is, removing the `employee_addr` nested object and moving its properties to the root of the document.

This document is the result of an aggregation pipeline and I need to add another step to it

How can I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1. `$replaceRoot` - Replace the input document with new document.

   1.1. `$mergeObjects` - Merge `ROOT` document with `employee_addr` object.
2. `$unset` - Remove `employee_addr` field.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          "$$ROOT",
          "$employee_addr"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "employee_addr"
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fcC9pbqu5gA)

Answer (score 1):

One option is using `$set` if you have only several fields to flatten or you want to flatten an object but not necessarily down to the root:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      city: "$employee_addr.city",
      street: "$employee_addr.street",
      apartment: "$employee_addr.apartment",
      employee_addr: "$$REMOVE"
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0HnblI3cGmf).

Oterwise, use @YongShun answer, which I was about to write, but @YongShun beat me to it :)